# Bae stands for?

Tags: abbreviations

If bae stands for 'before anyone else', when somebody mention salt bae (Nusret Gokce-the meat guy), does it mean he is the one doing that salting move before anyone else?

Answer (score 5):

As noted on [KnowYourMeme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/second-civil-war), Nusret Gökçe became famous in 2017 after [one of his Instagram posts](https://www.instagram.com/p/BO9dI9ujWNI/?), in which he slices a steak and sprinkles salt onto it down his forearm, went viral. Twitter user lolalissaa [reposted another video](https://twitter.com/lolalissaa/status/817912233997074434?) of his with the hashtag #saltbae, which was then adopted by others.

As Jason B has noted, *[bae](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bae)* is slang for a romantic partner;

> Your bae is someone you are romantically involved with or in love with. [informal]

as Collins puts it. It's almost certainly a derivation of *babe* or *baby*; *before anyone else* or *beyond all else* as sometimes attested have the distinct ring of a [backronym](https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/books/features/the-top-ten-backronyms-a6925366.html). Certainly, *before anyone else* is not at all a common phrase, and it unlikely that anyone would have needed a shorter way to say it. *Salt Bae* therefore doesn't mean anything beyond a/my/the *bae associated with salt*, or *the person who I wish was my bae because he dispenses salt in an attractive manner*.

Plenty of people use hashtags like #boyfriend or #futurewife jokingly, to indicate an attraction to someone or to comment that something about them is attractive. It isn't surprising that the chef adopted this moniker: it's short, probably easier to pronounce than his real name for most people, and suggests that he is found attractive by the public, all valuable for marketing. Perhaps, given his nationality, it also serves as a play on *[bey](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bey)*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and really interesting point on "bey". I didn't know that the pronunciation is very close to the word "bey' in Turkish.

Answer (score 3):

I was pleased to see that **bae** is now actually defined in some main dictionaries and that I don't need to resort to using a less definitive reference.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bae):

> *US slang*
>   : SWEETHEART, BABY · If you're in a relationship, you've probably already begun frantically searching the web for the perfect gift for your *bae*, but don't fret—I have you covered. —Amanda Fama

From [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bae):

> *US*
>   *informal*
>
> A person's boyfriend or girlfriend (often as a form of address)
>
> *‘I'm going to see my bae’*
>   *[as name] ‘Bae just made me tacos’*
>   *‘what's wrong, bae?’*
>
> **Origin**
>   Early 21st century: abbreviation of baby or babe.

These dictionaries trace its origin back *baby* or *babe* (as per the Oxford link) and not to **before anyone else**—even though that does seem to be something that has since been ascribed to it.

Regardless, it's still an affectionate slang term, and it isn't meant to be used as a replacement for *before anyone else* in normal language use.

(I have never heard *salt bae* before, so I cannot comment on that specific instance.)

Comment: It has also crossed the atlantic, and is in use by young people in the UK

Comment: This definition may fit better than "before anyone else" I guess for "salt bae". Nusret Gökçe is a Turkish restaurant owner making this particular salting movement; when he cooks or serves meat, he salts the meat with a weird but very famous way. So "salt baby" he is, maybe!

Answer (score 1):

BAE is short for "Birleşik Arap Emirlikleri" in Turkish, that is United Arab Emirates, where he had opened his first overseas restaurant. When the salt thing became popular, he kept hashtagging BAE alongside the word "Salt" to promote his UAE establishment.

Comment: That is very interesting! Do you have a source for that information?

Comment: Well, I cannot find a Congress report on this. What would qualify as source?